# Heroku Template Error - looking for partials in the wrong directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So I'm learning Rails and working through Michael Hartl's tutorial.

When I deploy to Heroku, I get the infamous "We're sorry but something went wrong."

The app runs just fine on the local development server.

Heroku logs say:

```
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 112ms
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial layouts/header with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: </head>
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: <body>
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:     13: 
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:     14: <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:     15: 
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:     <div class="container">
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__112987114114249875_31386580'
2012-06-27T15:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:       <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
```

If I'm reading this correctly, it's looking in `/app/app/views` for the header partial.  This is wrong - it should be in `/app/views`.

On my development machine a file `_header.html.erb` is in `app/views/layouts`.

So why did Heroku add the extra `app` directory?

Comment: That's certainly strange.  It might be worth running `heroku restart` in your console to restart your instances.

Comment: I've done so.  The logs still give me the same error.

Comment: I continued working on the tutorial just viewing the site in development.  After doing another git push after adding site features, this error disappeared.  Very strange.

Comment: You probably forgotten to `git commit` the partial.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I realized my mistake: I did `git commit -am "commit_message"`, omitting `git add .` before it which resulted in leaving the new files out of the commit.

According to `git help commit`:

> -a, --all
>
> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told `git` about
>   are not affected.

After adding the untracked files, new commit and `git push heroku master` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and it's because the partial file was `haml`, but my Gemfile had `haml` as in `development` group only.

I converted to Slim, which I use for all the rest of the app, and that was it.

So basically, the server couldn't find the file because it had an unsupported extension (which was somehow available in development env).